# Executing WRKSPLF command from java to view spooled files and get the results

Tags: java, ibm-midrange

I want to use WRKSPLF command in java to work exactly as it works in AS400.
Is there any way i can run this command in java and get the output ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Nope.

But you can use the SpoolFileOpenList method along with your own UI...
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzahh/javadoc/com/ibm/as400/access/list/SpooledFileOpenList.html

Comment: To expand on the answer, IBM i commands like WRKSPLF don't write to STDOUT, so there is no simple way to capture the output and redirect it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to be able to execute WRKSPLF from a browser, try [IBM i Access for Web](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/access/web.html).  It's probably already loaded on your IBM i.  An alternative is IBM i Navigator.  https://my.ibmi.com:2005

Comment: Also, if iNavigator is installed, it's likely that some more focused commands such as wrksplf.exe, wrkprt.exe, etc., are also installed.